# Allow '.' (dot) in only number input in console

Tags: c#

I have a code

```
string _val = "";
Console.Write("Enter your value: ");
ConsoleKeyInfo key;

do
{
    key = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
    {
        double val = 0;
        bool _x = double.TryParse(key.KeyChar.ToString(), out val);
        if (_x)
        {
            _val += key.KeyChar;
            Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && _val.Length > 0) 
        {
            _val = _val.Substring(0, (_val.Length - 1));
            Console.Write("\b \b");
        }
    }
}
while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("The Value You entered is : " + _val);
```

that allow only number input. But how can I allow a '.'(dot) symbol, because I want to work with float numbers?

Comment: In general you're doing this sort of oddly. You're getting the actual key that was pressed but you could instead just use `Console.ReadLine()` to read all the users input. Then you would have no problem reading values like 1049.4839

Comment: But how I can ban a letters in this case?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal It looks like he's trying to filter what the user inputs. Like not allowing letters to be typed.

Comment: I need to allow for input only numbers and dot.

Comment: Instead of attempting to parse only the last character entered, try adding the character to your input string and parsing the whole thing. I'm not sure if Double.TryParse() will properly parse something like "123." though.

Comment: Can you check if the key is ConsoleKey.Period or ConsoleKey.Decimal. as well.

Comment: The standard design for this problem is to instead read a whole line parse it, and if unsuccessful re-prompt the user to enter another line.  It's dramatically easier to code than what you're trying to do.  Is it vitally important that you do this, rather than the more standard approach?  Note that allowing both digits and a period isn't *too* hard, but ensuring that the number typed is a valid number is harder. You also need to ensure there is only one decimal, for example, and then there's the potential issue of comma separators or currency symbols, or different decimal separator characters.

Comment: The usual approach as described by Servy (reading a whole line first, then validating the input) may have (I haven't checked and am not entirely sure TBH) the added advantage of supporting the shell's stream redirection capabilities much better, i.e. reading input from a file or from another process' output.

Answer (score 0):

```
string _val = "";
Console.Write("Enter your value: ");
ConsoleKeyInfo key;
do
{
    key = Console.ReadKey(true);

    if (char.IsNumber(key.KeyChar) || key.KeyChar == '.')
    {
        _val += key.KeyChar;
        Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
    }
    else
    {
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && _val.Length > 0)
        {
            _val = _val.Substring(0, (_val.Length - 1));
            Console.Write("\b \b");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if ((key.KeyChar >= 48 && key.KeyChar <= 57) || key.KeyChar == 46)
   {
         _val += key.KeyChar;
        Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
   }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using magic numbers like this.  It's completely unclear to the reader what these numbers mean.  Instead you can simply use methods like `char.IsDigit`, or in the case of the decimal compare the char to the actual character literal, rather than the numeric representation.

Comment: @Servy I agree your comment about unclear code. But I think you write the answer about question. This help us more. Thanks.

Comment: @cutefather: If you are going to do that then at least '0', '9' and '.'.